# Extract Numeric Value using SAS

Tags: sas

My raw data is in the form

```
Var
12 A+
14 A+
AB+ 19
AB:20
20
25
27 New
```

I want to extract the numeric portion of it only.

Can anybody please help me how to process this data in sas.

Thank you in advance. Rgds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the COMPRESS function, which takes the form

```
COMPRESS(<source><, chars><, modifiers>)
```

**Update:**
There are many ways to achieve this. As per their comments, RWill and Keith provide the best solutions:

```
var2=input(compress(var,compress(var,,"d")),best.);
```

or even better:

```
var2=input(compress(var,,"kd"),best.);
```

Comment: A variation is to use an embedded compress function within another compress function, where the embedded one removes all difits, and this is used as the modifier for the second compress function (removes all characters other than those digits).  Something like:
    var2 = compress(var,,compress(var,,"d"));

Comment: Even easier is to add the "k" modifier, which keeps the characters listed rather than removing them. So the code will look like : var2=input(compress(var,,"kd"),best.);

Answer (score 3):

Just as @itzy mentioned above, Perl regular expression will do with ease:

```
  var2=prxchange("s/[^0-9]//",-1,var);
```

This will remove all non-numerical characters. 
  In this statement, 's/' begins a string, [^0-9] means all non-numerical characters. -1 defines an until-end match.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the regular expression function built in to SAS. Start by reading in the whole line as a character variable, and then use `prxmatch` or one of the other regular expression functions to extract just the numeric component using the `\d` wildcard.